# How do I call Bootstrap modal functions without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

In my app I am removing my jQuery dependencies.
I still use Bootstrap though. How can I call modal functions - `$('#myModal').modal('show')` and similar - without using jQuery?

Comment: Are you using any other framework or pure Javascript ?

Comment: Doesn't Bootstrap require jQuery?

Comment: How about something like https://github.com/thednp/bootstrap.native?

Comment: The core of my app with be native JS. I am moving UI elements to a separate set of modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap (js), jQuery is required.

All you need to do is target the selector and toggle the CSS display. I did not include the Bootstrap (js) library, but I did keep the CSS.

Example taken from: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

```js
const showModal = (selectorOrElement, show) => {
  if (typeof selectorOrElement === 'string') {
    selectorOrElement = document.querySelector(selectorOrElement)
  }
  selectorOrElement.style.display = show ? 'block' : 'none'
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.close')).forEach(closeButton => {
  closeButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let header = e.target.parentElement
    let content = header.parentElement
    let dialog = content.parentElement
    let modal = dialog.parentElement
    showModal(modal, false)
  })
})

showModal('.modal', true)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap presentation/dismissal include some animations and style effects that - I assume - are happening in the modal('show') and modal('hide'). I don't think toggling display style will look the same.

Comment: @dugla you realize it is not possible to use Boostrap without jQuery?

Comment: In the general sense, you are correct. However I am partitioning my app to have sub-sections that rely only on JS, event-handlers when the interact with a Bootstrap component such as modal.

Answer (score 2):

I found this :

```js
bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.querySelector('#modal')).show()
```

It works on Bootstrap v5.3

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap.js requires jQuery per the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/).

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript plugins.

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware. However it should be possible to build sub-sections of a large app - that will be import'able modules - that rely on css manipulation and standard DOM manipulation function calls. In fact I already do this with afew of my classes.